# Qual è il significato di "portare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola ho letto:

> A parte il fatto che Daniela non aveva voluto studiare. Lei che poteva, non aveva voluto. Non ne aveva voglia. Diceva che *non era portata*. Proprio vero nella vita chi vuole non può, e chi può non vuole.

Non riesco a capire il significato dell'espressione "non era portata" nel brano precedente. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Essere portati per (qualcosa) vuol dire avere un dono o attitudine particolare...  Per esempio "non sono portato per la matematica" significa "non sono bravo / non ho un dono (o attitudine) / non mi riesce bene studiare la matematica".

Comment: E di solito si usa in espressioni negative come, ad esempio,  "non sono portato per ..."?

Comment: Sì, ma anche spesso in espressioni positive -- esempio:  "Mia figlia è molto portata per le lingue".

Answer (score 10):

Come riporta il [vocabolario](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/portato_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) *Treccani*, sinonimi di *essere portato per* sono:

> (essere) *adatto, incline (a), predisposto, tagliato, versato (in)*.